# I can't run two threads at once with arguments

Tags: python, multithreading

I can't execute the second thread after starting the first.

This is my attempt at running two threads:

```py
def test1(foo):
    print(foo)


def test2(bar):
    while True:
        time.sleep(3)
        print(bar)


threading.Thread(target=test2('Test2')).start()
threading.Thread(target=test1('Test1')).start()
```

The first thread loops forever (*as intended*), but `threading.Thread(target=test1('Test1')).start()` is never executed.

Output:

```py
Test2
Test2
Test2
...
```

Expected output

```py
Test1
Test2
Test2
Test2
...
```

---

Edit: Simplified the entire question body with new functions

Comment: Not the problem, but it's best not to use `self` as an parameter name to a standalone function - by convention `self` is used to refer to an object's instance within a class.

Comment: I am seeing a missing closing paren before the start on the thread construction line for play

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix, use the [`args`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread) argument for `Thread`:

```
threading.Thread(target=dummyAction, args=('Working',)).start()
threading.Thread(target=play, args=(pathToFile,)).start()
```

In your first example this is incorrect:

```
threading.Thread(target = play(pathToFile)).start()
```

because it actually *calls* function `play(pathToFile)` and sets its return value to `target` *before* creating and starting the thread. So it was merely coincidence that it seemed to work. In fact the `dummyAction()` function would execute in a new thread, but the `play()` function was actually executing in the main thread.

And that explains why your second example did not to start the second thread; the program is blocked running `dummyAction()`.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you're supposed to pass the arguments to the threads:

```
threading.Thread(target=dummyAction, args=('Working',)).start()
threading.Thread(target=play, args=(pathToFile,)).start()
```